# std::reduce is failing to compile when types of container and initial value differ

Tags: c++, numeric

I ran into a portability issue with `std::reduce()`.

There's a call to `std::reduce()` that compiles in Visual Studio, but not with gcc. It's not clear to me from the cpp documentation if the issue is a bug in gcc, or if Visual Studio is not respecting the spec.

I am using an initial integer value. I want to reduce from a container of pairs, and am using a custom binary operator with signature `int (int &&, const std::pair<int, bool> &)`.

The code given below contains my version of `reduce()` in the `MyImpl` namespace. The code provides a switch to use either my version or the `std` version.

Could someone, please, take a quick look at the [source code](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6f87317656f95133) and let me know what is it that I am doing wrong?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

#include <numeric>
#include <vector>

namespace MyImpl
{
    template <typename IIter, typename T, typename BinaryOp>
    T reduce(IIter first, IIter last, T val, const BinaryOp &bOp)
    {
        for (; first != last; ++first)
            val = bOp(std::move (val), *first);
    
        return val;
    }    
}

int main ()
{
    std::vector<std::pair<int, bool>> vv {std::pair{1, false}, std::pair{2, true}, std::pair{-1, false}, std::pair{7, true}, std::pair{10, false}, };

#define MY_IMPLEMENTATION
#ifdef MY_IMPLEMENTATION
    // I get the results that I expect using my implementation of reduce
    std::cout << MyImpl::reduce (vv.begin (), vv.end (), 0, [] (auto &&value, const auto &ve)
    {
        return (ve.second ? (value + ve.first) : (value));
    });
#else
    // std's implementation gives an error
    std::cout << std::reduce (vv.begin (), vv.end (), 0, [] (auto &&value, const auto &ve)
    {
        return (ve.second ? (value + ve.first) : (value));
    });
#endif

    return 0;
}
```

Here's the error -

By the way, if you click on the "source code" link, you will see the Coliru code.

```
main.cpp: In instantiation of 'main()::<lambda(auto:16&&, const auto:17&)> [with auto:16 = std::pair<int, bool>&; auto:17 = int]':
/usr/local/include/c++/12.1.0/type_traits:2565:26:   required by substitution of 'template<class _Fn, class ... _Args> static std::__result_of_success<decltype (declval<_Fn>()((declval<_Args>)()...)), std::__invoke_other> std::__result_of_other_impl::_S_test(int) [with _Fn = main()::<lambda(auto:16&&, const auto:17&)>&; _Args = {std::pair<int, bool>&, int&}]'
/usr/local/include/c++/12.1.0/type_traits:2576:55:   required from 'struct std::__result_of_impl<false, false, main()::<lambda(auto:16&&, const auto:17&)>&, std::pair<int, bool>&, int&>'
/usr/local/include/c++/12.1.0/type_traits:3050:12:   recursively required by substitution of 'template<class _Result, class _Ret> struct std::__is_invocable_impl<_Result, _Ret, false, std::__void_t<typename _CTp::type> > [with _Result = std::__invoke_result<main()::<lambda(auto:16&&, const auto:17&)>&, std::pair<int, bool>&, int&>; _Ret = int]'
/usr/local/include/c++/12.1.0/type_traits:3050:12:   required from 'struct std::is_invocable_r<int, main()::<lambda(auto:16&&, const auto:17&)>&, std::pair<int, bool>&, int&>'
/usr/local/include/c++/12.1.0/type_traits:3292:44:   required from 'constexpr const bool std::is_invocable_r_v<int, main()::<lambda(auto:16&&, const auto:17&)>&, std::pair<int, bool>&, int&>'
/usr/local/include/c++/12.1.0/numeric:283:21:   required from 'constexpr _Tp std::reduce(_InputIterator, _InputIterator, _Tp, _BinaryOperation) [with _InputIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<pair<int, bool>*, vector<pair<int, bool> > >; _Tp = int; _BinaryOperation = main()::<lambda(auto:16&&, const auto:17&)>]'
ma
```

Comment: It would help if you would provide the actual compiler error. However, `0` is an `int` literal, so both versions of `reduce()` should be returning `int`, and both lambdas should be deducing `auto&& value` as `int&& value`. I don't see any cause of an error here.

Comment: [`std::reduce (5)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/reduce) _"...T must meet the requirements of MoveConstructible. and binary_op(init, *first), binary_op(*first, init), binary_op(init, init), and binary_op(*first, *first) __must be convertible to T__..."_

Comment: I don't think the return value in the lambda can be converted to `int`.

Comment: Thanks @RichardCritten for posting that one line. That answers it. How do I mark the question as answered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My question has been answered! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Per cppreference:

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/reduce

> `T` must meet the requirements of MoveConstructible. and `binary_op(init, *first)`, `binary_op(*first, init)`, `binary_op(init, init)`, and `binary_op(*first, *first)` must be convertible to `T`.

That means there are *4 possible ways* for the binary operator to be called by `std::reduce()`, but your lambdas are only accounting for one of them: `binary_op(init, *first)`, which works fine for `MyImpl::reduce()` because that is how it is calling the operator.  But that is not guaranteed for `std::reduce()`, as you can clearly see in the very 1st line of the error message:

> main.cpp: In instantiation of 'main()::<lambda(auto:16&&, const auto:17&)> [with auto:16 = std::pair<int, bool>&; auto:17 = int]':

Your `std::reduce()` lambda is expecting to be called as `binary_op(init, *first)`, but `std::reduce()` is actually calling it as `binary_op(*first, init)` instead.

So, you may need something more like this instead:

```
template<typename T>
inline constexpr bool is_int_v = std::is_same_v<std::remove_cvref_t<T>, int>;

std::cout << std::reduce (vv.begin (), vv.end (), 0,
    [] (const auto &arg1, const auto &arg2)
    {
        if constexpr (is_int_v<decltype(arg1)>)
        {
            if constexpr (is_int_v<decltype(arg2)>)
            {
                // binary_op(init, init)
                return arg1;
            }
            else
            {
                // binary_op(init, *first)
                return arg1 + (arg2.second ? arg2.first : 0);
            }
        }
        else if constexpr (is_int_v<decltype(arg2)>)
        {
            // binary_op(*first, init)
            return arg2 + (arg1.second ? arg1.first : 0);
        }
        else
        {
            // binary_op(*first, *first)
            return arg1.second ? arg1.first : 0;
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: Remy, thanks for posting the workaround to my issue. 
In the future, if I need something like this, I will stick to std::accumulate.

Comment: @Catriel yes, your `MyImpl::reduce()` is more like what `std::accumulate()` does internally rather than what `std::reduce()` does.

Comment: Remy, yes, you are right. My stub reduce is not a reduce algorithm at all. I just wrote it to illustrate my interpretation of the binary operator. I read Visual Studio's implementation of std::reduce. They kept the same binary operator type as std::accumulate, which brings me to the next question. Is the requirement from the spec on the binary operator really needed?  Why wasn't it made compatible with std::accumulate?

Comment: @Catriel There are plenty of online articles (on StackOverflow and elsewhere) that explain the difference between `std::accumulate()` and `std::reduce()`, and why `std::reduce()` was introduced in the first place (hint: parallelization) and how it works (ie, grouping/reorganizing values in arbitrary order)

Comment: Hi Remy, thanks again for the reply. I realize now that the spec is ensuring a deterministic behaviour.

Comment: Or, if I really really need std::reduce, I'll probably do something like a struct - follow the link - https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5d273fd63502f493.